# Safe method to reference value type from object for later mutation

Tags: swift

I'm looking at best practice to manage external value types passed to a object when you want delayed mutation of the external value type. The core goal is to provide a friendly/conventional interface, while being more idiomatic.

My Current code uses UnsafeMutablePointer. And looks like this:

```
struct MutableData {
    var variable: Double = 1
}

struct Object
{
    var variablePtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>? = nil

    mutating func add(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>) {
      self.variablePtr = data
    }

    mutating func mutateLater() {
        self.variablePtr?.pointee = 10
    }
}

var mutableState = MutableData()
var compute = Object()

compute.add(data: &mutableState.variable)
compute.mutateLater()
```

While this works, I'm concerned about the lack of guarantees around the lifetime of the external struct that the pointer points to.

Are there ways to:

- Guarantee the struct lifetime while I'm pointed to it?
- Check the value types existence through pointer introspection
- Another means of rewriting this to use @escaping closures for later
  retrieval, without requiring a wacky external API?
- Other idiomatic way to write this that gets correct behavior and safety?